# Only show intersection of 2 selectors when both active in altair chart

Tags: python, visualization, altair, vega-lite, vega

I have made an Altair Visualization that contains 2 selectors on two different variables of my dataframe.

When I try to use one it works well -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLsPv.jpg

When I use the other selector, it works also fine -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZXVo.jpg

However when I use both selectors I would like to only show the intersection of both selectors and not what is shown here -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJbDb.jpg

Is it possible, to display the selection of each selector when only one of them is active and the intersection when both are active?

Edit: I add the code to this problem with sample data so hopefully its easier to reproduce.

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

cars = data.cars.url

alex = alt.selection_interval(
    on="[mousedown[event.altKey], mouseup] > mousemove",
    name='alex', resolve='intersect'
)
morgan = alt.selection_interval(
    on="[mousedown[event.shiftKey], mouseup] > mousemove",
    mark=alt.BrushConfig(fill="#fdbb84", fillOpacity=0.5, stroke="#e34a33"),
    name='morgan', resolve='intersect'
)

alt.Chart(cars).mark_rect().encode(
    x='Cylinders:O',
    y='Origin:O',
    color=alt.condition((alex & ~morgan) | (~alex & morgan) | (alex & morgan), 'count()', alt.ColorValue("grey"))
).add_selection(
    alex, morgan
).properties(
    width=300,
    height=180
)
```

I would like the chart to show the selection of "alex" when only the "alex" selector is chosen, "morgan" when only "morgan" is chosen and only the intersection, when both selectors "alex" and "morgan" are chosen.

Thank you so much in advanced!

Comment: It sounds like setting `resolve='intersect'` inside each selection could be what you want. If that doesn't work, please either provide the data your are using for `new_df` or reproduce this issue with sample data.

Comment: I reproduced the issue with sample data, but using resolve = "intersect" did not solve my problem. Is there a way to do it? Thanks so much!

Comment: Thanks for updating the example! `resolve` wont help here, sorry, I initially thought you had multiple subplots, which separate selections in each. The default behavior of a selection is that everything is selected when the selection is not used (`empty='all'`). Theoretically that means it should be enough with the condition `(alex & morgan)`, since when you use one of the selections, the other should stay uninitalized with all values selected. In practice it seems like both are cleared as soon as one is used and setting `clear=False` does not help. ...

Comment: ... This might be unintended, so check if there is any issue about it on the VegaLite issue tracker. You could also try setting the `init` param for the selections, but I tried briefly and didn't have much luck.